# a Foreign key referring to its own table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am completely aware that this question asked in this site, but im just a beginner, i just want a simple answer to my simple question, i think this might help other people wondering the same question.

```
create table Members(
MemberID int ,
MemberName varchar(30),
leftID  int,  
rightID int,
money int,
primary key(MemberID),
 Foreign key (rightID) references Members(MemberID),
Foreign key (leftID) references Members(MemberID)
)
```

will the Code above work? the foreign key will reference to the MemberID of the same table.
if you want to know, this is related to MLM database structure of members and the members directs.

Comment: Creating the table will work, but inserting will be a bit complicated because you can't defer the constraint checking in MySQL to the end of the transaction.

Comment: Never forgot to accept/upvote when answer is helpful